# The smallest integer $n$ for a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Along a stretch of motorway, breakdowns require the summoning of the breakdown services occur with a frequency of 2.4 per day, on average. Assume the breakdowns occur randomly and that they follow a Poission Distribution, find
>
> the smallest integer n such that the probability of n breakdowns in a day is less than 0.03.

How does one solve such a Question, My problem is :

I start attempting this like :

$$P(X>n)<0.03$$

$$1-P(X\leq n)<0.03$$

$$P(X\leq n)>0.97$$

$$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+......+P(X=n)>0.97$$

^ How does one compute this when n is unknown.

> After Thinking for a while, I proceeded thinking this means: $$\sum_{r=0}^{n} e^{-2.4} \frac{2.4^x}{x!}>0.97$$ but even then I don't know how  to solve this, or if this is the  shortest method.

---

I know one  can solve by trying out integers from $n=0$ to $n=1$ to $n=2$ and so on, and seeing at which point it gets larger than 0.97. But that is time consuming, and not a good method (I think).

Comment: "...not a good method (I think)" Why not? Because it looks tedious? Also, are you familiar with the concept of cumulative distribution functions?

Comment: @arne.b Yes I know the concept of cumulative distribution function, but I don't know how to apply that to this, can you please shows me how it's done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "the smallest integer n such that the probability of n breakdowns in a day..." as "n *or more* breakdowns in a day", then I do not think there is a better way. However, I disagree about your in/exclusion of the equal sign in your initial inequalities. (If one were interpreting it as "*exactly* n breakdowns" one should look for $P(X=n)<0.03$ and do somewhat easier calculations, but this seems to be a much less useful question to ask.)

What you are looking for is then

> "the probability that a real-valued random variable X with a given
>   probability distribution will be found to have a value less than or
>   equal to *x*."

This is a quote from the first sentence of [the cumulative distribution function (CDF) wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). However, when you look up the [Poisson distribution's CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) you will find that it, too, involves a sum term, so  is no easier formula than "sum of probabilities of individual events up to *x*".